updating access token in next auth
The application I'm working on, is using magic link to allow users to login. Once the user is logged in, they can proceed to register if they choose to.
Once the user is authenticated by clicking on the link sent to the email address, each user will get a JWT access token with following details.
{
  "email": "user@orli.tech",
  "iat": ......,
  "exp": ......,
  "iss": "...."
}

Authenticated user can do certain stuff including registering to the application. Once the user is registered, I want to update the token to include things such as id, name, address.
I tried following
For authentication & authorization, we have a dedicated express server. Under providers, I have only credentials to exchange magic link token to an access token.
NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            name: 'Auth using magic link',
            credentials: {
                token: { label: 'Token', type: 'text' },
            },
            async authorize(
                credentials: Partial<Record<'token' | 'action', unknown>>
            ) {
                // send credentials.magicLoginToken to backend and get token
                // decode token to  get the email address
                // then return the user object
                return { ...user, accessToken }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        authorized() {
            console.log('3')
        },

        redirect() {
            console.log('4')
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            console.log('1')
            if (!user) return token
            token.accessToken = user.accessToken
            return token
        },

        session({ session, token }) {
            console.log('2')
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            return session
        },
    },
    session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
    trustHost: true
})


With NextJs 14, in a server component I can access the session in the server component as follows. session has a function to update the details. Just for testing I added a button and added session.update() to click handler.
export default function DashboardPage() {
    const session = useSession()
    const onClick = () => session.update()
}

I noticed in the configuration passed to NextAuth, it's calling redirect, jwt, session, authorized in the exact same order. Is this how I'm supposed to refresh the accessToken, and would jwt be a place to get a new token?
